# HTML just run one script instead of two scripts I have typed

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Newbie here. I put two scripts (DataTables and chained dropdown) in one html file, here my code:

```
<!-- DataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.12.1/datatables.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.12.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabel-data').DataTable({
    search: {return: true,},
    paging: true,
    ordering: true,
    info: true,
    })
});
</script>
<!-- Chained Combobox -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#jenisbarang').on('change',function(){
                var jenisbarang = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'ambil_data.php',
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{
                        modul:'MerekTipe',
                        id:jenisbarang
                    },
                    success:function(respond){
                        $("#merektipe").html(respond);
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("Gagal Mengambil Data");
                    }
                })
            })

            $('#jenisbarang').on('change',function(){
                var jenisbarang = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'ambil_data.php',
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{
                        modul:'LokasiPJ',
                        id:jenisbarang
                    },
                    success:function(respond){
                        $("#lokasipj").html(respond);
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("Gagal Mengambil Data");
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    </script>
```

When I run the html file, it only run the dropdown script. The DataTables won't appear. But when I delete the dropdown script, the DataTables appears. I want to display both script at the same time. Please help me.

Comment: The datatables script uses jQuery, but you don't load jQuery until after it. You need to load jQuery before anything that uses it.

Comment: how to do it?

i have added:
<script>
$(document).load(function(){
$('#tabel-data').DataTable({
search: {return: true,},
paging: true,
ordering: true,
info: true,
}) 
});
</script>
<table id= "tabel-data" class="table table-striped table-bordered"> ...

i add it before the table that i want to use datatables on it, but it still not working, the datatables not appears. But if i delete the dropdown script it appears

Comment: Open page in browser, press F12, select `console` tab, refresh page (F5).   Research error messages, such as `$ is undefined`   Given the code you've provided, the `<script src=` tags are in the wrong order, move jquery to be first. then bootstrap js then datatables, *then* your scripts

Comment: Move the line `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the top, before the DataTables script.